# How to check columns with different value but same category

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables in my database.
I want to update value in one table retrieved from another table with condition on columns having different values.

Table 1

```
Shape     Rate
------- 
Round            
Heart    
Oval
```

Table 2

```
Shape     Rate
------- 
BR     2100
PS    2500
```

now i want to update Rate value in able 1 from Table 2 where Round means BR and Rest all means PS

How can I join these two tables using these values?

I am using oracle database.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to choose the appropriate row in `table2` to update `table1`.

Given your sample data, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
update table1 t1
    set rate = (select t2.rate
                from table2 t2
                where (t2.shape = 'BR' and t1.shape = 'Round') or
                      (t2.shape = 'PS' and t1.shape <> 'Round')
               );
```

You should really fix your data.  Two columns called `shape` should really contain the same values.

Answer (score 0):

`merge` is one of the ways:

```
merge into table1 tgt 
using table2 src
on (tgt.shape = 'Round' and src.shape = 'BR' or tgt.shape <> 'Round' and src.shape = 'PS')
when matched then update set rate = src.rate
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c74f31a51904ab8cbc226b36ea262a50)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
UPDATE TABLE_1
SET RATE = (
    CASE 
        WHEN SHAEPE = 'Round' THEN (SELECT RATE FROM TABLE_2 WHERE SHAPE = 'BR')
        ELSE (SELECT RATE FROM TABLE_2 WHERE SHAPE = 'PS')
    END
)
```